# How do i click popup save button using seleium python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I tried to save this page using this save button. but i failed to click on it using its class.

Code:

```
    driver.get('https://lexintell.com/case/case-details/605a3dc8f7b34594b97700b3/?search=')
    element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'fa-print')
    element.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'action-button').click()
```

N.B.: To view this page, you need to logged in.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-print-browser')
    prefs = {
        'savefile.default_directory': '/home/nasim/pdf/'
    }
    chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
```

after adding this as options, my issue has fixed

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using JavaScript

```
driver.execute_script("""
    document.getElementsByClassName('action-button')[0].click()
"""
    )
```

Comment: It stops executing after this line,

```element.click()```